# If Office.context.mailbox.item.addFileAttachmentAsync is called multiple times, callback is called only once

Tags: office-js, outlook-addin

As the title says, calling addFileAttachmentAsync multiple times in parallel (i.e. not nested) results in only one callback running. However, as seen on the UI, the file actually attaches, just that the callback doesn't run. As a result, the only way to attach multiple files is to attach them one by one, which is obviously not the ideal solution.

Comment: What is your code? Did you try to specify different functions for the callback?

Comment: Can you please share which Outlook platform you are using ie. Outlook web, PC desktop or Mac? And can you share your Outlook and Windows version numbers.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT This behaviour was observed on Outlook on the web, on Chrome.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev I ran a loop for multiple attachments and called Office.context.mailbox.item.addFileAttachmentAsync inside that loop.